# Scala Stream confusion

Tags: scala, recursion, stream, tail

Running:

```
lazy val s: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: 2 #:: {val x = s.tail.map(_+1); println("> " + x.head); x}
s.take(5).toList
```

I'd expect:

```
> List(2, 3)
> List(2, 3, 4)
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

And I get:

```
> 3
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Could you explain it to me?

Comment: Why would you expect `x.head` to return a list?

Comment: What confuses me is why on earth you'd want to put a `println` inside the definition of a lazy val.

Comment: @Dan: To find out when and how often the expression will execute (and what the various values will be when it does), I imagine.

Answer (score 6):

The reason that you're getting an `Int` instead of a `List` is that `s` is a stream of integers, so it contains integers, not lists.

The reason why you get 3 is that the tail of (1,2,3,4,5,...) (i.e. `s`) is (2,3,4,5,...) and if you map +1 over that, you will get (3,4,5,6,7,...) and the head of that is 3.

The reason why only one integer is printed is that the expression is only evaluated once to get the stream for the tail. After that only the stream returned by `s.tail.map(_+1)` is evaluated (which doesn't contain any print statements).

Comment: consider this: `val s: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: 2 #:: {val x = s.tail.map(1+); x take 10 print; x}` will print `3333...` and falls, so `x` seems to be a Stream of threes, not 3,4,5,... but it make no sense because then `s` should be a `Stream(1,2,3,3,3,...)`. I'm so confused, any advice, where I can read more about streams?

Comment: @4e6: Consuming more elements of a stream than have been generated yet inside the expression generating the stream, will cause infinite recursion (which will eventually blow up the stack). The reason that you get so many 3s isn't that the stream contains that many 3s (if it did they would be separated by commas), but that the print statement is executed so many times (because the logic recurses in circles and gets to the print statement again and again and again...).

Comment: @4e6 Consider what you wrote: to compute the third number, it needs to print the 10 first numbers. But how can it print the third number if it hasn't computed it yet? That's you you get an error.

Comment: sepp2k, @DanielC.Sobral, think I understand now. Many thanks and +1s :)

Comment: would it be correct to say that since stream uses memoization, the result of evaluation of println(x) is stored and therefore expression is never evaluated again ?

Comment: @Jamil: Well not so much the result of print as the result of the whole expression including print. But yes, that's correct. The expression is evaluated once and after that it just uses the result of the expression (the stream `s.tail.map(1+)`) without reevaluating the whole expression.